# Spring Security Oauth2 - Adding credentials to the AccessTokenRequest

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

With [this reference](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) to the Spring OAuth2 Client docs:

And the following section:

> If you desparately need password grants to work from a Java client, then use the same mechanism to configure your OAuth2RestTemplate and add the credentials to the AccessTokenRequest (which is a Map and is ephemeral) not the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails (which is shared between all access tokens).

How can the credentials be added to the AccessTokenRequest? Or more generally, how can I get a reference to the AccessTokenRequest or OAuth2ClientContext for the specific user of the request.

The reason why I need this is to avoid the UserRedirectRequiredException and the requirement to redirect to the authorize URL, as the Rest API I am accessing does not have a login page, but just a restful login api.

Supposedly the OAuth2ClientContextFilter should store the current request and context but I can't see how.

Comment: Ok, the session attribute scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext holds the client context

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `AccessTokenRequest`:

```
@Autowired
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

public void doSomething() {
  AccessTokenRequest request = 
    restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest();
  ...
}
```