# Spring OAuth2 OAuth2RestTemplate and resource owner password

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to figure out how to have my Spring OAuth2Client use the resource own password scheme when authenticating to my Authorization server using Spring OAuth2. I don't get what the documentation states:

> If you desparately need password grants to work from a Java client, then use the same mechanism to configure your OAuth2RestTemplate and add the credentials to the AccessTokenRequest (which is a Map and is ephemeral) not the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails (which is shared between all access tokens).

How do I do this? Since I'm building both the authorization server and the client my client is a trusted source and I do not need to go through the auth code flow.

I saw this answer: [Spring Security Oauth2 - Adding credentials to the AccessTokenRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649282/spring-security-oauth2-adding-credentials-to-the-accesstokenrequest)

But, I'm not exactly clear how to achieve this so that I don't have to go through the redirect. Can you do this through a basic auth header?

Update: 
I think I got it working

I create a ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails and create a new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider

Then get a token using the credentials and set the token in the injected oauth rest template.

```
OAuth2AccessToken token = accessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(details, request);
restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(token);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: So finally what's the question? If it works so it definitely correct))

Comment: The question was how to use the resource owner password authentication scheme in a web application. I had a Spring Boot UI server and a Spring Boot auth server I was creating. Although the documentation says not to use it for a web application, IMO resource owner password authentication should be fine for a first party trusted application, right?

Comment: First of all, let's make it clear. Oauth is authorization standard. Which means it provides standard ways to authorize already authenticated user on third-party resources. If you expose your username and password to those resources (which is exactly what password flow does) so there is no any meaning of using Oauth. But sometimes, and you have an example, it is necessary both to authenticate the user and to authorize him with Oauth. So in this case you can definitely use this approach. Hope it helps

Comment: I understand this completely now :) My intention was to never allow third party applications to use password flow, but to ONLY allow my own application to use password flow. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: What request are you sending to the server to get this working? Any examples would be very helpful!